# D365 Phone number field - remove icon

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I cant seem to find a way to delete this little phone Icon.

[image]

Im currently trying to remove this Icon via JavaScript but I cannot find a way to remove that Icon. Nothing I found in the formContext is useful. I thought that the control of `formContext.getControl("myprefix_businessphone")` has the icon in it, too. But the options there are for the field only (as far as I've found).

Answer (score 1):

This is click-to-dial functionality for any phone number field in CRM UCI form. Anything you try from the [internet suggestion](https://crmtipoftheday.com/134/how-to-block-click-to-call-in-crm/) is going to be unsupported which may break in future release.

Other choices are - you can have a new custom plain text field to store the phone number data instead of phone number format, or develop your own PCF control to render the same existing field without icon.